# How to load a new view on click of the login page on checking the condition of username and password in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, authentication, xcode4.3

I want to redirect to the new view on the click of the sign in button by checking the login condition that is if user gives the correct username and password redirect to new view in Xcode 4.3.2, i am using the soap service to fetch the username and password.

I tried googling out, but i was not able to get a valid one.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

i'd go for modalview controller-> simply present modal view controller when your app starts in appdelegate or your mainviewcontroller, after the user gives you correct credentials, just dismiss this modal view controller and there you go.

[UIView Controller class reference - presentViewController method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

there are also many other(custom) ways how to achieve that (more less you're playing with views/animations,etc), this one is maybe the most straightforward one